# Two tables values matching equals a value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

This has really baffled me and I don't know what to do.

Basically I am wanting to display some data if the user name matches the user name on the data's table. You'll understand when you see the code.

So here is the code I am using to try display it on my main page:

```
<?php
if($login_user == $feedbackuser)
{
echo'
<p>Hey</p>
';                       
}
?>
```

Then here is my code connecting to the SQL data base and trying to call information from each table.

Connecting to table 1:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['user'];
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT user FROM feedback WHERE user='$user'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$feedbackuser=$row['user'];
?>
```

Connecting to Table 2:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['username'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user_check' ");



$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user=$row['username'];
$admin=$row['admin'];

if(!isset($user_check))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

So basically I want a sentence to be displayed if their username from table 1 matches user from table 2.

If you could help me further that would be great. If you take a look at the screenshot before I explain more:

https://gyazo.com/48bbdad68fa0e7f4e4ccd5969a37f614

So if the username from table 1 matches user from table 2 then "writing" from table 2 will be displayed on the page.

Comment: I think you haven't explained what kind of issue you are having.

Comment: consider reading about [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Is there only one row per user in both the tables? If yes, then a single query could be written as follows: `SELECT u.username FROM users u
           INNER JOIN  feedback f
                   ON  u.username = f.user
                  AND  f.user = '$user' `.
Now, if you'd like to access certain columns specifically, you'll have to include those in `SELECT` - for example, `SELECT u.username, f.col1, u.col2,.....`. Also, please consider switching over to prepared queries: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The screen shot is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single query with `left join` to see if any feedback exists for the user, e.g.:

```
SELECT u.username, f.user
FROM users u LEFT JOIN feedback f ON u.username = f.user
WHERE u.username=$user_check;
```

This way, you will get both `username` and `feedback`.

- If `feedback` is `null` but user is not `null` then that means no record exists in `feedback` table.
- If both are `null` that means user is not present

I am assuming `user` is the master table. If that is not the case, you can use `feedback` as master table by reversing the order in left join.